# MaxActive / wait may not work, thousands of connections are still being created

Tags: go, redis

[Go redigo] MaxActive / wait may not work, thousands of connections are still being created.

Go version: 1.14
github.com/gomodule/redigo v2.0.0+incompatible

Step 1: Wrote code as below, wait is true, maxActive is 99.
Step 2: Deploy the container in k8s. Doing load testing/
Step 3: Using `netstat -nat | grep 6379 | wc -l`, you can find the connection all more than maxActive for each pod.

```
# netstat -nat | grep 6379 | wc -l
xxbp-blacklist-6c9fcb57f4-66jpw
2897
xxbp-blacklist-6c9fcb57f4-6pdrp
12853
xxbp-blacklist-6c9fcb57f4-9kpjs
252
xxbp-blacklist-6c9fcb57f4-hkwj7
165
```

Step 4, In aws elasticache redis server monitoring tool, you can find the connections go up to 10000 totally.

Code --redisutil.go--

```
package redisutil

import (
    "AuthService/config"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
    "log"
    "time"
)

var pool *redis.Pool

func InitializeRedisPool() error {
    conf := config.GetConfig()
    conf.AutomaticEnv()
    pool = &redis.Pool{
        MaxIdle:     10,
        MaxActive:   99,
        Wait:        true,
        IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
        Dial: func() (redis.Conn, error) {
            c, err := redis.Dial("tcp",
                conf.GetString("redis_host"),
                redis.DialPassword(conf.GetString("redis_token")),
                redis.DialTLSSkipVerify(conf.GetBool("redis_tlsskipverify")),
                redis.DialUseTLS(conf.GetBool("redis_usetls")))
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("Redis error during connect! " + conf.GetString("redis_host") +
                    " redis_token" + conf.GetString("redis_token") +
                    " redis_tlsskipverify:" + conf.GetString("redis_tlsskipverify") +
                    " redis_usetls:" + conf.GetString("redis_usetls"))
                log.Fatalln(err)
                return nil, err
            } else {
                return c, nil
            }
        },
    }

    //Check whether conn can be set up correctly
    conn, err := pool.GetContext(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    return nil
}
 

func VerifyBlacklist(token string) bool {
    conn := pool.Get()

    defer conn.Close()

    exists, err := redis.Bool(conn.Do("EXISTS", "blacklist:"+token))
    if err != nil {
        // handle error return from c.Do or type conversion error.
        log.Println("Redis error: error return from c.Do or type conversion error.")
        log.Println(err)
        return false //Use this temporally, friend for testing
    }

    return exists
}
```

--  code main.go ---

```
    err := redisutil.InitializeRedisPool()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("Redis error! InitializeRedisPool Fail!")
    }
```

-- API will invoke thousands of redisutil.VerifyBlacklist during load testing ---

Comment: Are the tcp status   established ?   your cmd should be 'netstat -nat | grep 6379  | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l'

Comment: You should file a issue with Redigo if you have evidence that Redigo does not limit the number of active connections to MaxActive.  Before doing so, you should double check your assumptions by checking the [active count](https://godoc.org/github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis#Pool.ActiveCount).  It's possible that the application is dialing and closing a large number of connections.  Increment a counter in the dial function to determine how frequently dial called.

Comment: Hi, Miffa Young. Thanks a lot. Good point. 
I checked 'grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l', almost all pods connections count is exact 20 when high load raised.  (one go to 34 lessly)
Two more question:
1  Why it is 20, it should be 99 as my maxActive. Surely the load is very heavy, and it should go up to 99.
2   Should it be an defect : 'netstat -nat | grep 6379 |  wc -l" is more than 1000(even 10000 sometimes) ? will it impact the function of pods?
Thanks

Comment: Since I am using AWS elasticache redis, I talked with AWS support.
He thought my connection pool does not work, because "new connections" of AWS redis is arrived 10000. But "curr connections" of AWS redis is only 280.
So, can anyone check why redigo connections not work? Any error configure? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any other code in the application that uses the pool? Is there more than one pool?   (1) Check to see if the application is dialing and closing connections frequently by adding a counter or logging to the dial function.  (2) Set MaxIdle to same value as MaxActive to see if that solves the problem.  If so, the MaxIdle value is too ow.

Comment: Is there any other code in the application that uses the pool?(John: No) Is there more than one pool?  (John: No)
 (2) Set MaxIdle to same value as MaxActive to see if that solves the problem. If so, the MaxIdle value is too ow. –
Good point, it works well after I change maxidle to 100.
The `netstat -nat | grep 6379 |grep ESTABLISHED| wc -l` highest value is 200. (Previous it is 20)
The `netstat -nat | grep 6379 |grep WAIT| wc -l` is not much. (Previously it is more than 10000)
This is interesting maxIdle impacts maxActive, and the real active connections is 2 times of maxIdle, why?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Following error is encountered - "redigo: no sentinels available; last error: dial tcp <IP>:Port: socket: too many open files" if the value of MaxIdle is kept smaller than MaxActive. If the two parameter are given same value then no error is encountered. @CeriseLimón any idea why such a behaviour is observed?